# How to remove duplicate values from dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of data that I am using to create a drop down logic with.But there is a series of duplicate values when I create the drop-down using :

```
                    <select>
`                     `{
                        this.state.statistic_table.map((obj) => {
                            return <option value={obj.period}>{obj.period}</option>
                        })
                    }</select>
```

The long list of arrays contains a number of duplicate period values which are actually months. So in the dropdown I would get each and every value. I would like to eliminate the duplicates from the dropdown. 
How could I achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: Please include the demo of your array data in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to acheive that could be to use the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) API after mapping your array  :

```
{Array.from(new Set(this.state.statistic_table.map(obj => obj.period))).map(period => {
    return <option value={period}>{period}</option>
})}
```

And then converting it back to an array using `Array.from` to map your component with it

Comment: A similar solution to the one below, but you directly gave me the solution I needed . Thanks. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I will fix that on this way:

1) Using some events e.g. `componentDidMount` where you need to filter your array on next :

define an empty array in the state:

```
this.state = {
 let filteredArray = [];
}
```

On mount filter them :

```
componentDidMount() {
    let uniq = Array.from(new Set(this.state.statistic_table));
    this.setState(uniq);
}
```

If the object type is correct you can do something like this:

```
 <select>{
      this.state.filteredArray.map((obj) => {
           return <option value={obj.period}>{obj.period}</option>
      })
 }</select>
```